# .Net 4 client profile language pack detection C#

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I have two related questions:

Is there a way we can detect which language pack has been installed if any, on a machine with .Net 4 client profile?

The language packs Microsoft provides are here: [Language packs for .Net 4 Client profile](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23067)

Microsoft provides separate installers for .Net 4 Client profile for each language, can we for instance detect if the version installed is a German version?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what is your real issue, but for me the dll is installed into that folder (win7) (you can see in the folder the language abbreviation)

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_31bf3856ad364e35\
```

this is the dll file name

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.resources.dll
```